# How a non-root user sudo to another non-root user without password?

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo, users

As root, created a new non-root user on RHEL 7.5

```
appuser:x:1903:1903:appuser:/home/appuser:/bin/bash
```

A non-root user to be able to sudo to `appuser`,

`sudo -u appuser`

without a password,

What are the changes required on RHEL 7.5?

Comment: That `sudo su - appuser` is a horrendous security breach: you're giving full root access to the user who has permission to do that. Instead, just give the account permission to get to `appuser`, so they would `sudo -su appuser` (here, `-su` is two flags, `-s -u`). No need for the `su` command anywhere.

Comment: @roaima Query edited. `sudo -u syslog` does not work. It asks for the password for current user

Comment: Of course it does. That's what `sudo` does.

Comment: Ugh, I wish people wouldn't give us the security lecture when it's irrelevant to my use case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can edit the "User privilege specification" section of `/etc/sudoers`, adding:

```
non-root-user ALL = (appuser) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This will allow `non-root-user` to run all commands as `appuser`. `non-root-user` will not be allowed to run commands as root.

Note that errors in `/etc/sudoers` can make a system unusable. The file should only be edited with:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

This special editor checks the `sudoers` file for errors before saving and refuses to save it if errors are found.

Comment: But `-r--r----- 1 root root 1225 Jun 12 12:04 /etc/sudoers`. Do you think this is customised permision?

Comment: E45 error on modifying the file with vi editor

Comment: It looks like `-r--r-----` is the standard file mode for `/etc/sudoers`. Refer to my edited answer for how to edit it.

Comment: This still gives `visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied` if I do not have root privileges, so I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat The `sudo visudo` part is just a clarification on how to (safely) edit `/etc/sudoers`, i.e. how to configure the system so that an unprivileged user can authenticate as another unprivileged user without being prompted for a password. _That step_ requires root access, of course (and the OP does have it). Apparently, the question is not about how to configure a non-root user using a non-root user. Does this clear your doubts?

Comment: Fair enough, my case isn't quite the same as the OP. I don't have the ability to temporarily use root permissions so I guess I'm out of luck. This seems like a bit of a flaw in Linux's model.