# sudo -su vs sudo su -

Tags: sudo, users, root, non-root-user

On RHEL 7.5, I created a non-root user and would like to switch from one non-root-user to another non-root-user, without password.

First tried,  `sudo -u user1`, command syntax error

then tried, `sudo su - user1`, asks for passwd,

1) Why it asks for password?

2) How `sudo -su user1` different from `sudo su - user1`?

Comment: Being able to switch from one non-root user to another without a password would be a massive security hole; I'm pretty sure it's not possible (at least, without special configuration to allow it e.g. changing /etc/sudoers).

Comment: Possibly [related context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478460/how-a-non-root-user-sudo-to-another-non-root-user-without-password#comment874665_478460).

Answer (score 3):

1. I’m guessing `sudo su - user1` asks for a password because `sudo` is configured to ask for a password to switch to root.
2. `sudo su - user1` switches to root (if `sudo` allows it) and runs `su - user1`, which switches to `user1`. `sudo -su user1` runs a shell as `user1`. In the first case, `su` is a command, run by `sudo`; in the second, it’s the two options `-s` and `-u` given to the `sudo` command.

`sudo -u user1` fails because you’ve told `sudo` to do something as `user1`, but you haven’t told it what; you need to specify a command to run, or `-s` to start a shell.

See [su vs sudo -s vs sudo -i vs sudo bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35338/86440) for a more general discussion.